# verificar se o nome já existe na base de dados firebase e c#

Tags: c#, firebase

Ora viva não consegui encontrar resultados para a minha pergunta e vou tentar por aqui.
É assim, tenho uma base de dados em firebase numa aplicação em c# e queria saber se era possível verificar se o nome inserido é igual ou diferente do nome inserido na base de dados.
Agradeço a vossa compreensão.
Fico há espera de resultados.

Vou colocar alguns bocados de código para uma melhor resposta

Começei por criar uma clas "Usuario" e fiz uma função "EIgual_Registo"

```
public static bool EIgual_Registo(Usuario user1, Usuario user2)
    {
        if (user1 == null || user2 == null) { return false; }

        if (user1.Nome == user2.Nome)
        {
            erro = "O nome inseirdo já existe na nossa base de dados!";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

De seguida criei um código onde vai fazer as verificações na página "Registo"

```
private void Butao_registar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region Condicao
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox_Nome.Text) &&
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox_Pass.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Favor preencher todos os campos!!");
            ActiveControl = textBox_Nome;
            return;
        }
        #endregion

        FirebaseResponse res = client.Get("Contas/" + textBox_Nome.Text);
        Usuario ResUsuario = res.ResultAs<Usuario>();// resultado da base de dados
        Usuario CurUsuario = new Usuario()
        {
            Nome = textBox_Nome.Text
        };


        if (Usuario.EIgual_Registo(CurUsuario, ResUsuario))
        {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario()
            {
                Nome = textBox_Nome.Text,
                Pass = textBox_Pass.Text,
                Genero = comboBox_Genero.Text,
                Aniversario = dateTimePicker_Aniversario.Text
            };

            SetResponse set = client.Set(@"Contas/" + textBox_Nome.Text, usuario);

            MessageBox.Show("O Usuário foi inserido com sucesso!");
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Usuario.MostraErro();
            textBox_Nome.Clear();
            textBox_Pass.Clear();
        }

    }
```

eu faço a inserção dos dados nos respetivos campos, e o código realmente faz a pesquisa pelos nomes todos e realmente vê que encontrou um nome igual.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora fazendo com um outro nome.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sério se alguem estiver aí para me ajudar agradeço imenso obrigado!

Comment: Não tendo ideia de como está organizada sua base de dados, uma solução que funcionará é: leia todos os registros, do primeiro até o último, e compare com o nome desejado. Se encontrar pare, se chegar ao fim então o nome não existe na base.